# PrimeNG MessageService on constructor doesn't display

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, primeng

I have a Manage evaluations page and a Generate evaluation page. When I create an Evaluation from the second page it navigates to the first one sending the generated Evaluation on state like this:

```
saveEvaluation() {
  this.evaluationService.addEvaluation(this.evaluation).subscribe(ok => {
    if (ok === true) {
      this.router.navigate(['/main/evaluations'], { state: { evaluation: this.evaluation } });
    }
    else
      this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: '', detail: 'Error al conectar con el servidor' });
  });
}
```

And I try to handle this in my Manage evaluations page setting a Message with message service once the constructor read the object from history state:

```
constructor(
private messageService: MessageService,
private examService: ExamService,
private evaluationService: EvaluationService,
private userService: UserService) {

  if (window.history.state.evaluation)
    this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Evaluación generada', detail: 'Se agregó la evaluación para el usuario ' + window.history.state.evaluation.applicant.name});
}
```

But it doesn't works. The MessageService is provide in compomonent module and ToastModule is imported there:

```
...
providers: [
  MessageService
]
...
```

I tried to move the `if (window.history.state.evaluation)` to `ngOnInit()` method but it doesn't works.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue with `MessageService` but with the `window.history.state.evaluation`. Why not use `queryParams` instead?

Comment: Instead of `window.history.state.evaluation` you should use `this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state`.